# Keep original colors in pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode?

Tags: pdf-tools, coloring

**Q:** can I keep the original colors for plots and photos in
`pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode`?

`pdf-view`'s midnight minor mode allows me to change the
foreground and background colors of a PDF document to something
that matches my color theme via `pdf-view-midnight-colors`.

But: when I turn on `pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode`, *all* of the
PDF's colors are rendered in shades of the foreground and
background colors I specified.  I read a lot of PDFs with color
graphs, plots, and photos, and these lose their original colors in midnight
mode.  Is there any way to *keep* the original colors on things
like graphs and figures?